# SSIS Package Execution from SQL Agent & DTExec: Parameters or Variables?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

I have an SSIS Package, to which I will be giving some input values at Runtime. I want to have the possibility to execute it either from SQL Agent, or also from DTExec from the File System. From what I found, if I run DTExec from a file (a .ispac compiled project actually), I can only set Variables with the /SET option, not Package Parameters. If I however want to run it from the Agent, or from the Server in general, its better and easier to use Parameters.
At the moment I have created empty Parameters and Variables as placeholders for inputs, and additional Variables with expressions as a switch, to use Parameters if Variables are empty.
This is all a little redundant though, so I need to know if there is any way to only use Parameters, and set it from DTExec when running it from the file system? Or does anyone have any better idea in general?

Answer (score 0):

When executing an SSIS package using DTExec the best, easiest, and most portable approach to setting params is to use an "XML Configuration File." Creating and using such a file enables you to execute a package in Dev using one set of values (such as SQL Server Instance Name and Password) and another set in production.

To create an XML Configuration File click on the SSIS tab in BIDS in your package, choose package configurations and you can then choose what XML file will contain the settings and their initial values.

Comment: I'm using the Project Deployment Model and from what I know that's not available.

Comment: According to msdn you can use dtexec with the Project Deployment Module. MSDN - "You can also execute packages using dtExec." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx) And if you can use dtecec you can use a package configuration file. You may have to move the package configuration file (an xml type file) to the target machine.